# Losing formatting while sending mail

Tags: java, html, jakarta-mail, velocity

I am using velocity

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

context.put("commentText", commentText);
context.put("link", link);
```

When I put `commentText` the formatting is maintained that is white spaces etc.

However in the mail body I get one single line of text. I am not sure where and how I should maintain the formatting and line breaks.

```
StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
Template t = Velocity.getTemplate("AcceptMilestone.html");
System.out.println("after Velocity . get template ;;;;;;;;;");
t.merge(context, w);
System.out.println("after Velocity . merge content ;;;;;;;;;");
String s = w.toString();
```